# Identify wall piece with jungle or Meso-American print?

Tags: part-identification

I found an older piece and was wondering if anyone knew the part or set it came from. [image]

Answer (score 8):

This is [LegoBrick 1 x 2 x 5 with Jungle Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2454px6&name=Brick%201%20x%202%20x%205%20with%20Jungle%20Pattern&category=%5BBrick,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=9), which appeared in 2 sets from 1999: [5986-1 Amazon Ancient Ruins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5986-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) and [5936-1 LegoSpider's Secret / Señor Gomez's Expedition](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5936-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

(I first searched BrickLink for "Aztec" and "Mayan", which pulled up some Indiana Jones sets, and then tried "Jungle", which had this on the first page of results.)